# Avoid jumping content when using fonts with changing width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fonts, font-size

Some type of fonts such as `georgia`, `gilroy`, etc, have variable width with numbers, so number 1, has a difference width to number 5. This causes the content to constantly jump between single digit changes when using a time counter for example. I don't mind it jumps on additional digits such as from 9 to 10, or 99 to 100, but I do not want it to jump between single digit changes.

How can I use `georgia` font without causing below jumps? I also do not wish to have a fixed width for the time counter, because it could grow significantly and I don't want to have empty space when the time counter is small.

```js
document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener("click", function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelector('#time').innerHTML++ 
  }, 100) 
});
```

```css
.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.font-serif {
  font-family: Georgia;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex items-center">
<div class="flex-1">
  <div class="bg-blue"></div>
</div>
<div class='font-serif'>
  <time id="time">0</time>
</div>
  </div>
  <button id="start">start</button>
</div>
```

**However if I use a different font such as `sans` content does not jump:**

```js
document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener("click", function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelector('#time').innerHTML++ 
  }, 100) 
});
```

```css
.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.font-sans {
  font-family: font-sans;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <div class="flex-1">
      <div class="bg-blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='font-sans'>
      <time id="time">0</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="start">start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: For some fonts  font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums; will give fixed-width digits. However, this appears not to be so for georgia. You may need to use JS to align things correctly.

Comment: @AHaworth
Thanks! it worked with georgia! You can add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some fonts `font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;` will give fixed-width digits.

[I didn't seem to get this to work with Georgia but pleased to hear that it works for you].

Comment: Thanks! I found a nice post on twitter that shows how it works: https://twitter.com/sulco/status/1293862293139337217